# Db107s bridge rectifier

Tags: bridge-rectifier

I have a circuit from a dehumidifier. It has a db107s bridge on it. I tested the ac voltage in @240v but the output is dc @335v - is this normal or could it have something else connected which is boosting voltage as I tested it on the board?

Comment: 240V is rms, 335 is a normal peak for DC with small load

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for that. I have no idea, so guessed it should be the same voltage :o